# Append special characters in html tags

Tags: javascript, html

How to append special characters in html tags?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <script>
        tool_tip_str = '!#$%^&&*()<>\'\"';
        var html = '<div title="' + tool_tip_str + '"> text is here </div>';
        document.write(html);
    </script>
</body>
```

This code is producing the result

```
<div "="" title="!#$%^&amp;&amp;*()&lt;&gt;'"> text is here </div>
```

But it should produce the

```
<div title="!#$%^&&*()<>\'\""> text is here </div>
```

why odd characters

> "=""

are appending in result? Is there any way to show the single quotes or double quotes with out black slashes ?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/CAsF2/

Comment: no, not working fine. :) would you please inspect the source and see?

Comment: and double quote is also not showing in title

Comment: Fixed for quote http://jsfiddle.net/CAsF2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CAsF2/3/)

I got this result:

[image: Image of source]

[image: Image of outcome]

using this:

```
tool_tip_str = '!#$%^&&*()<>\'&quot;';
```

If you want to change all special characters to HTML entities, then you could write a function like:

```
function change(mystring)
{
  return mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
}
```

and then do:

```
tool_tip_str = change(tool_tip_str);
```

But obviously, you'd have to change everything in `change()` to get it exactly how you wanted.

Comment: great - would you please specify the function in js that converts the double quotes in "&quot;" format?

Comment: It isn't a function. `&quot;` is HTML. It's [Special Character](http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html) @Suleman, so should work without any modification to your javascript.

Comment: I mean, Is their any function in javascript that converts the quotes into special characters ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body>
      <script>
         tool_tip_str = '!#$%^&&*()<>\'\"';
         tool_tip_str = tool_tip_str.replace('"','&quot;');
         var html = '<div title="' + tool_tip_str + '"> text is here </div>';
         document.write(html);
     </script>
 </body>
```

Might need to convert the " into an html entity prior to outputting.

Comment: Tweaked it a little so that it performs a replace on the " to make it &quot;

Comment: Why didn't you just change `"` to `&quot;`? :P

Comment: I took the assumption that this was test code and eventually would get converted into a function that took a title as a parameter.  In fairness if not then you're right that it's just easier to type it in :p